# RGBD-slam start without enter keyword(space)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
My question is simple i want to start rgbd-slam without enter space .... means when i run rgbd-slam its automatically start to build a map. Can anybody help me ? how i handle this ? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65082/rgbd-slam-start-without-enter-keyword(space)/) by [Qubaish Bhatti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4290/qubaish-bhatti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qubaish Bhatti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4290/qubaish-bhatti/) on 2013-06-14**:
i need help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello Qubaish,

there is a rosparam "start_paused" which is per default true, just set it to false via the launchfile of the rgbdslam node

```
<rosparam name="start_paused" value="false" />
```

---

Originally posted by [goetz.marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4958/goetz.marc/) with karma: 203 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1